# Multithreaded queue with timed capabilities

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex, condition-variable

I am implementing a multi-threaded queue in C++ with timed capabilities i.e. `pop` and `push` can have a timeout as an extra parameter.

The basic code looks like following.

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue() = default;
    // Usage of a mutex makes the Queue class neither copyable nor movable
    Queue(const Queue&) = delete;
    Queue& operator=(const Queue&) = delete;

    T Pop(const std::chrono::microseconds& micro_secs=std::chrono::microseconds::max())
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

        if (!cond_var_.wait_for(lock, micro_secs, [this]() { return !queue_.empty(); }))
        {
            // TODO: throw
        }

        auto item = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();
        return item;
    }

    void Push(T& item, const std::chrono::microseconds& micro_secs=std::chrono::microseconds::max())
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_, std::defer_lock);
        if (!lock.try_lock_for(micro_secs)) // for this std::mutex should be std::timed_mutex.
        {
            // Couldn't acquire lock during the specified time.
            // TODO: throw
        }
        queue_.push(item);
        lock.unlock();
        cond_var_.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_var_;
};
```

For `Pop()` function, in order to have a timeout on the condition variable, **the mutex should be** `std::mutex`.

But for the `Push()` function to have a timeout in acquiring the lock, the mutex should be a `std::timed_mutex`. `try_lock_for` works if the **mutex** wrapped in `unique_lock` satisfies `TimedLock` requirements.

I would be pleased to hear any workarounds to solve this issue.

`Pop()` requires the **mutex** on the queue to be `std::mutex`, since `condition_variable::wait_for()` works on `std::mutex`. On the other hand, `Push()` requires the **mutex** on the queue to be `std::timed_mutex`. How I can solve the issue with a single lock on the queue i.e. a single mutex in my `Queue` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need a timeout for `Push`? The lock is never held for any significant period of time. `Pop` may need to wait for the element to become available in a previously-empty queue; but `Push` would never have to wait.

Comment: I think I do still need to add a timeout for `Push`. The reason being that eventually I am intending to use this `Queue` to inside a `threaded dispatcher queue`. So ideally I would like the clients of the `dispatcher` to be able to `invoke`/`send` a job to the queue with a timeout.

Comment: But why "with a timeout"? What could prevent a job from being added to the queue immediately? And if there's a limiting condition (e.g. the queue is limited in size, and `Push` would need to wait for it to shrink), then you would need a condition variable for that, and would then use `wait_for` same as `Pop`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @IgorTandetnik. It made me rethink over the requirements. I agree with your comment. A `Push` with a timeout seems redundant. I reckon I confused this with the synchronous `invoke` api in `dispatcher` which in any case has to be handled with a separate `condition variable`/`mutex` pair. Even a synchronous `invoke` should not hold the lock on the `queue` until the pushed item is consumed, rather should make the `queue` available for other producer threads, in which case a timeout for pushing to the `queue` seems senseless. Thank you once again.